# Column count in oracle10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am working with oracle10g. How can I determine the number of columns in a relation specified as a SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a look at DBMS_SQL package. A select statement can include n columns, thus you need to parse it manually using PL/SQL.

DBMS_SQL.REC_TAB structure will give you plenty of information about your select statement.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can **dba_tab_columns** synonym.

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME='NAME_HERE_RELATION';
```